# In SQL Server, how to find strings between many identical characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Like the title, I want to find strings between two identical symbols, like

```
declare @str varchar(255);
set @str = 'I want to + get + all results + out + between two + plus sign'
```

So the intricacy here is `@str` has many identical plus symbols, and I just want to take out the string `all results`.

How should I do that with T-SQL?

Comment: What version of SQL do you have? 2016 and Azure have this as a native function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Comment: Hello, thanks for letting me know but unfortunately I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x), though there are other potential candidates for duplicates. Replace `+` with `,` and it's the original classic.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql).

```
select replace(@str,'+','')

--I want to  get  all results  out  between two  plus sign
```

If every + sign has a space before and after and you want to clean the spaces up, put a space after the + sign

```
select replace(@str,'+ ','')

--I want to get all results out between two plus sign
```